# How to store an external HTTP_REFERER in a cookie in PHP for later retrieval?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I would like to have a PHP code to do the following:

- User comes to my website from a link in an external website, in other words, the HTTP_REFERER is not from my own domain.
- Save this HTTP_REFERER in a cookie

In another part of my website I will check to see if this cookie is present and include the saved referer with the user profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving cookies is pretty easy (see [PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for details).

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    setcookie("externalRefer", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time()+3600);
}
```

Retrieving is just as easy:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['externalRefer'])) {
    echo $_COOKIE['externalRefer'];
}
```